# Excanvas does not work in IE8 at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, canvas, excanvas

I simply cannot get excanvas to work at all. I have tried everything I can think of. I am even uploading the examples that come with excanvas to my website and testing them and they do not even work. I don't know if it has something to do with my server or what, but I haven't seen a working excanvas image yet.

for instance... I this example comes with the excanvas package and it does not work for me... does anyone know what this could possibly be? thanks

http://www.javascriptkids.com/tools/excanvas/examples/example1.html

Comment: I just opened that link in IE8 and it worked fine. Not able to reproduce error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `Tools > Options > Security > Custom level... > **Binary and script behaviors** (under <i>ActiveX controls and plug-ins</i>-section)`

Change it to either Enable or Administrator approved.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer! The problem may be in security settings of browser. You must add http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com to Internet options -> Security -> Trusted Sites!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was almost certainly because of the "compatibility mode" that was introduced in IE8... Add this to your page to force IE to use the IE7 compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```